# Building a Binary tree in lisp

Tags: lisp, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to build a binary tree is lisp. The function should do this

```
(buildBST  ‘(6 9 2 1 7))  -> (6  (2 (1) ()) (9 (7) ()))
```

The code we have so far will keep returning the error

```
> 7 nil arguments should be of type real
```

Here's our code

```
(defun buildBst (lis)
    (cond 
        ((null lis) 0)
        ((atom lis) lis)
        (t (if ( >(car lis)(car(cdr lis)))
                (buildBst( cdr lis))
                (buildBst(cdr lis))))))
```

Comment: You're not checking for the case where `lis` only has 1 element. You do `(> (car lis) (car (cdr lis))`, but if there's only 1 element, `(car (cdr lis))` will be `NIL`.

Comment: Both alternatives of your `if` statement do exactly the same thing? Is that really what you want there?

Comment: You don't seem to be combining the recursive call with what you already have. So the final result won't be a tree, it will just be the result of the innermost recursion.

Comment: both 'null lis' and 'atom lis' should check for one element

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would be to make an insert function:

```lisp
(defun tree-insert-element (tree element)
  (cond ((tree-null-p tree) 
         (make-tree element nil nil))
        ((< (tree-value tree) element) 
         (make-tree (tree-value tree)
                    (tree-left tree)
                    (tree-insert-element (tree-right tree) element)))
        (t 
         (make-tree (tree-value tree)
                    (tree-insert-element (tree-left tree) element)
                    (tree-right tree)))))
```

Thus when you want to insert a whole bunch you can do this:

```
(defun tree-insert-list (tree list)
  (reduce #'tree-insert-element list :initial-value tree))
```

Of course, you'll need to define the functions the insert function uses as I really don't care how you choose to model a tree. From the look of the expected result I guess `make-tree` might just wrap `list*`, but thats not the only way to make a tree!