# What does suffix "p" mean in common lisp functions?

Tags: common-lisp, naming-conventions, predicate

See for example: https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str#empty-emptyp-s

Or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33379360/12400477

I have seen this in several places, and I don't know what it means. Does the `p` suffix indicate the type the function returns? Does it always mean it returns a bool? Why do there seem to be two alternative symbols for the same function in the first example?

Comment: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/cltl/clm/node69.html "By convention, the names of predicates usually end in the letter p (which stands for ``predicate'')."

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/p-convention.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Common Lisp there are a bunch of [naming conventions](https://www.cliki.net/naming+conventions). Adding a `p` or `-p` is for functions which return a truth value.

This does not mean that the function will return only `t` or `nil`. Other values of *true* are also possible:

Example of a predicate which will return a different value from `t` for *true*.

```
CL-USER 1 > (digit-char-p #\a)
NIL

CL-USER 2 > (digit-char-p #\1)
1                              ; any object other than nil
                               ; also means *true*
```

The convention to use `?` instead is coming from the Scheme programming language.

Answer (score 2):

It stands for predicate, i.e. functions with a yes or no answer. Example: integerp (is it an integer?), realp, rationalp, etc..

Answer (score 2):

The extension 'p' stands for 'predicate'. A predicate is a test which returns a Boolean result of true or false. The idea of a predicate applies to most if not all languages.

An example is 'zero predicate' of a parameter, x, which returns true if x is zero, or false if it is not zero.

The style varies from language to language, and also it depends on the predicate name. Clojure's style is to add a question mark. Common Lisp's style is to add a 'p' to the name, usually. Common Lisp has an exception for predicate names containing a hyphen, when '-p' is added. The first example seems to want to do both styles, '?' and 'p', depending on what style the user is used to.

Coding of a predicate involves making a test and returning the result instead of acting on it.

```
Python:

def zerop (x):
   return x == 0

# zerop (0) => True
# zerop (1) => False

Common Lisp:

(defun my-zero-p (x)
   (= x 0))

; (my-zero-p 0) => t
; (my-zero-p 1) => nil
```

Comment: There's also an exception for `NULL`. If it were following the convention it would be `NULLP`, but it came from earlier dialects of Lisp and predates the naming convention.

Answer (score 2):

Because nobody mentioned it clearly yet, I wanted to add:
you use `-p`, if the symbol to which you want to attach `p` contains already one or more `-`. If not, you just attach `p` wihout the hyphen.

So `one-word` would become `one-word-p`, but `blue` would become `bluep`.

Answer (score 0):

The *p* stands for 'predicate' and the Lisp Hyperspec says:

**predicate** n. a function that returns a **generalized boolean** as its first value.

**generalized boolean** n. an object used as a truth value, where the symbol nil represents false and **all other objects** represent true. See boolean.

**boolean** n. an object of type boolean; that is, one of the following objects: the symbol **t** (representing true), or the symbol **nil** (representing false). See generalized boolean.

If the function returns nil or T I (and others use *?* instead of *p*).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).